# Using jquery-sparkline.js in Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to using jquery-sparkline.js library for a project in Angular 4 and I don't know how to import this library into Angular 4 and implement below code for example:

```
 $('#sparkline3').sparkline([5, 6, 2, 9, 4, 7, 10, 12], {
     type: 'bar',
     height: '164',
     barWidth: '7',
     resize: true,
     barSpacing: '5',
     barColor: '#f96262'
 });
```

I have used below import, but it doesn't work:

```
import  $   from 'jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js';
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: just use import 'jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js'

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried but when I want to use below code:
 $("#sparkline10").sparkline([2,4,4,6,8,5,6,4,8,6,6,2],

the compiler says:

property 'sparkline' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Do you have any comment?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using directive. Here is a way without using directive. For me its working.

First Move your jquery.sparkline.js to external folder like , "/external/js/jquery.sparkline.js".

Then Use create element like this.

```
initSparkline(){

    let s = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    s.type='text/javascript';

    // TODO: Move this call to ngDoChange event 
    s.text = "$(function() { setTimeout(function(){ $('#inlinesparkline').sparkline();}, 2000);})";

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, s);
    }

}
```

and call it as you want. and in html.

```
<div id="inlinesparkline">50,60,30,35,25,10,50,20,25,40,45,60,30</div>
```